# Existence of a Vector in an Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Let V be an inner product space and let $v \neq v'$ be vectors in $V$ . Show that there exists a vector $w \in V$ satisfying $\langle v,w\rangle\:\neq \:\langle v',w\rangle$.

As $v-v'\neq 0$, we get 
$$\langle v-v',v-v'\rangle >0$$
which implies 
$$\langle v,v-v'\rangle -\langle v',v-v'\rangle >0$$
$$\langle v,v-v'\rangle >\langle v',v-v'\rangle $$

Let $w=v-v'$. I am not sure if my argument is correct. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: Correct, and quite tidy and clever, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v-v'\ne 0\,$ is assumed. And $w$ is wanted with $\langle v-v',w\rangle\neq 0\,$. 
Then $w=v-v'$ does the job because an inner product is positive definite.

This is merely a short reformulation of the correct argument given in the OP.